# file_exists retorna False mesmo o arquivo existindo

Tags: php, html

No sistema estou usando o `file_exists` para ver se a imagem existe no diretório,  o problema é que sempre retorna `false` mesmo a imagem existindo no diretório, já fiz quase todos os testes possiveis e mesmo assim retorna `false`.

**Código:**

```html
<?php    
  $Image = "http://megaki/uploads/windows/173/1731534093656.jpeg";

if (file_exists($Image)) {
echo "O arquivo $Image existe";
} else {
echo "O arquivo $Image não existe";
}
?>
```

Ao executar retorna a mensagem:

```
O arquivo http://megaki/uploads/windows/173/1731534093656.jpeg não existe
```

O diretório está correto quando crio o diretório dou permissão `077` e mesmo assim não consigo resolver já estou a 2 dias a tentar resolver e não consigo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: use `file_get_contents` depois salve o content em um arquivo local ou verifique diretamente com `fopen`

Answer (score 1):

Geralmente, usa-se `file_exists` para testar a existência de um arquivo físico, e não um endereço do mesmo como recurso http.

No seu caso, me parece que você está tentando checar se um arquivo que está em um diretório do seu projeto existe ou não. Nesse caso, use o caminho físico do arquivo no seu servidor para verificar.

Assim:

```
define('ROOT_DIR', 'diretório/raiz/do/projeto');

$file = ROOT_DIR . '/uploads/windows/173/1731534093656.jpeg';

var_dump(file_exists($file));
```

**Dica**

Pra descobrir a pasta padrão do projeto automaticamente, recomendo usar a variavél `__DIR__`.

Nas minha aplicações, costumo usar apenas o `index.php`, então não costumo ter problemas com essa constante variando o valor por usar um script em outra pasta, por exemplo.

Comment: tentei de todas as formas e mesmo assim nao deu acho que tever ser algum tipo de permissão de pasta